# Capturar el HTML de un SELECT, que usa el Plugin editableSelect

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$("#idSelect").editableSelect({
    effects: 'fade',
    duration: 'fast'
});
```

Para tomar el valor, realizo:

```
$("#idSelect").val(); // Funciona bien!
```

Ahora quiero tomar el HTML del select (todos los OPTION) :

```
 $("#idSelect").html(); // Pero esto no funciona
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendría que emplear [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) para encontrar elementos Hermanos en el `DOM` ya que el plugin crea una lista con la clase `es-list`.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#idSelect").editableSelect({
        effects: 'fade',
        duration: 'fast'
    });
    var items = $('#idSelect').siblings('.es-list').find('li');
    $(items).each(function(index, el) {
        console.log($(el).text());
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js"></script>

<select id="idSelect">
    <option value="1">Uno</option>
    <option value="2">Dos</option>
    <option value="3">Tres</option>
</select>
```